# How to set django ModelFormset widget?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have an inlineformset created by inlineformset_factory. 
One of the inlineformset field is a DATE field and I want to add a calendar widget.

How could I set this widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a modelform for your inlineformset and in this form you can specify your widget for your field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.inlineformset_factory

> inlineformset_factory(parent_model, model, **form=ModelForm**,
>   formset=BaseInlineFormSet, fk_name=None, fields=None, exclude=None,
>   extra=3, can_order=False, can_delete=True, max_num=None,
>   formfield_callback=None, widgets=None, validate_max=False,
>   localized_fields=None, labels=None, help_texts=None,
>   error_messages=None